# Removing items from RecyclerView.Adapter causes OutOfBounds exception

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to build a simple list using RecyclerView, that would allow me to add/remove items.

I'm able to remove the items, but it seems like the position is not being 're-calculated' after I remove an item.

For example, I have 20 items in the list, if I remove the last item, the position is 19 (as it should be). The item gets removed from the list, but when I click to remove the last item again, the position is still 19, it should be 18:

```
D/RecycleViewTest: Remove at Position: 19
D/RecycleViewTest: Remove at Position: 19
```

Which results in the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recycleviewtest, PID: 1763
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19, Size: 19
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
        at com.example.recycleviewtest.MainActivity$1.onRemoveClick(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.recycleviewtest.SimpleViewHolder$2.onClick(SimpleViewHolder.java:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I'm removing the items the following way:

```
itemList.remove( position );
adapter.notifyItemRemoved( position );
```

Do I need to make additional call to some kind of function, so that the list gets "re-calculated"?

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    List<SimpleViewModel> itemList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        itemList = generateSimpleList();

        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(itemList);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.simple_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator() );
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new SimpleAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position)
            {
                Log.d( "RecycleViewTest", "Click at Position: " + position );
                adapter.notifyItemChanged( position );
            }

            @Override
            public void onRemoveClick( int position )
            {
                Log.d( "RecycleViewTest", "Remove at Position: " + position );
                itemList.remove( position );
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved( position );
            }
        });
    }

    private List<SimpleViewModel> generateSimpleList()
    {
        List<SimpleViewModel> simpleViewModelList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            simpleViewModelList.add(new SimpleViewModel(String.format(Locale.US, "This is item %d", i)));
        }

        return simpleViewModelList;
    }
}
```

This is my RecyclerView.Adapter (SimpleAdapter):

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<SimpleViewModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
    private onItemClickListener mListener;

    public SimpleAdapter(final List<SimpleViewModel> viewModels)
    {
        if (viewModels != null) {
            this.models.addAll(viewModels);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener( onItemClickListener listener )
    {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface onItemClickListener
    {
        void onItemClick( int position );
        void onRemoveClick( int position);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ((SimpleViewHolder) holder).bindData(models.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
        return R.layout.item;
    }
}
```

Here is my RecyclerView.ViewHolder (SimpleViewHolder):

```
public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView  simpleTextView;
    private ImageView imgRemove;

    public SimpleViewHolder(final View itemView, final SimpleAdapter.onItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        simpleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.simple_text);
        imgRemove      = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgRemove);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if( listener != null )
                {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    if( position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION )
                    {
                        listener.onItemClick( position );
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        imgRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if( listener != null )
                {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    if( position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION )
                    {
                        listener.onRemoveClick( position );
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void bindData(final SimpleViewModel viewModel) {
        simpleTextView.setText(viewModel.getSimpleText() );
    }
}
```

Any hints please on where am I going wrong with this? Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I just realized that even though the animation for removal is 'played', no actual items are removed, they simply 're-appear'..

Comment: have you tried notifyItemRangeChanged(position,getItemCount()); after item removed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your Adapter's constructor:

> ```
> private List<SimpleViewModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
> private onItemClickListener mListener;
>
> public SimpleAdapter(final List<SimpleViewModel> viewModels)
> {
>     if (viewModels != null) {
>         this.models.addAll(viewModels);
>     }
> }
> ```

The list you're passing into this constructor isn't retained by the adapter. Instead, the *contents* of the list are copied into the adapter's own, **separate and different** list.

That means that later on, when you execute

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRemoveClick( int position )
> {
>     Log.d( "RecycleViewTest", "Remove at Position: " + position );
>     itemList.remove( position );
>     adapter.notifyItemRemoved( position );
> }
> ```

The item is removed from `itemList`, but it **is not** removed from the list in the adapter.

You must either remove the item from the adapter's copied list, or you must change the adapter so that it shares the same list as the activity. Probably the easiest thing would be to change the adapter:

```
private List<SimpleViewModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
private onItemClickListener mListener;

public SimpleAdapter(final List<SimpleViewModel> viewModels)
{
    if (viewModels != null) {
        this.models = viewModels; // instead of copying the contents
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this after remove the item 
   mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, it looks like other people have been using an additional method called `notifyItemRangeChanged` which sounds like what is going on. So after doing `itemList.remove(position);`
try also doing

`adapter.notifyItemRemoved( position );`

`adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemList.size());`

Comment: What is the need of `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged`?

Comment: "Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items starting at position positionStart have changed." From the offical Recycler View docs. Thought that since it seems to still be 19 when deleting again, the range needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

The `getAdapterPosition()` return a range positions of `1 - n` and your list has a range positions of `0 - n`.

Try as follow

```
itemList.remove( position - 1 ); //to normalize
adapter.notifyItemRemoved( position );
```